# How to express this individual in Description logic

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, description-logic

I want to express this in dl, [Protege view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqwQ5.png).

How can I express the individual inclusive gateway1 which is from type inclusiveGateway?

```
{inclusiveGateway} ≡ (inclusivegateway1) (inslusiveGateway2)

name: inclusiveGateway
id: inclusiveGateway1
gatewaydirection: unspec
```

if a object property exists:

```
flowsinto: task1
```

Couldn't find an example how to do it for this case, just some equivalanceRelation for different classes, eg. `Man≡ Person`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you mostly got no answer is that your formulation is totally confusing.

Based on your image, and that's all I understood, you want to express those OWL axioms in DL syntax:

```
inclusiveGateway(inclusivegateway1)
gatewayDirection(inclusivegateway1, "unspecified")
name(inclusivegateway1, "Inclusive Gateway")
id(inclusivegateway1, "inclusivegateway1")
```

Not sure whether this answers your question. As a comment, common naming convention is camel-case and class names starting with an capital lettel.

Comment: well im not a native speaker, but i give my best to express my thoughts

Comment: Me neither. Maybe a little bit more structure and even some formatting (e.g. relevant entities of your ontology) could improve reading and understanding. Fair enough, glad to hear that your question could be answered.

Comment: Okay i will try to putt more effort into formating the next time. You helped me a lot, i really couldnt find how to express such relations after hours!!

Comment: Based on your example i translated my axioms into dl syntax. Thank you so much, this was really helpfull @AkSW!!! Lately i posted a lot, never used Stackoverflow before. As a human being i try to learn from my mistakes and hopefully do it better in the future. Never wanted to offend anybody. Overall i am happy about every peace of help. A working marathon day is over. T-15 days till i have so submit my thesis :P

Comment: @Richy as a further tip on how to use StackOverflow: if you get an answer that you find helpful, instead of thanking the author in a comment, consider upvoting or accepting the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: okay @JeenBroekstra i tried that, i dont let me do it due my low reputation. It says it wont changed the pubclicity displayed