# Applying Description Logic to a model

Tags: rdf, owl, bpmn, description-logic

im kinda new to dl. I tried to adapt the knowledge from this post: [How to express this individual in Description logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663153/how-to-express-this-individual-in-description-logic/38671157?noredirect=1#comment64728109_38671157)

AKSW kindly helped me out to describe axioms in dl. I applied the knowlede to my Model. I just wanted to double check, not making any design errors (you dont need to check every detail). This is how the model looks like BPMN:
[BPMN Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h26a6.png)

I tried to copy it into this question for 10 min, but when copying it the formatation was totally messy( another thing i need to learn :P). Sorry for not putting it directly into this question.
[DL Logic.doc](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=70010549144644699146)

edit: how can i describe a object property with domains and ranges in dl?

> **object property**: travelTo
>
> with the **domain**: France, Germany
>
> and **Ranges**: Italy, Spain
>
> **i would do it as fallowing:**
>
> travelTo(*France*, *Italy*)
>
> travelTo(*France*, *Spain*)
>
> or ---------------------------
>
> *France*(travelTo,*Italy*)
>
> *France*(travelTo, *Spain*)
>
> *Germany*(travelTo,*Italy*)
>
> *France*(travelTo, *Spain*)

any suggestions?

best regards Richard

Comment: I feel I should warn you that with the number of your questions that get downvoted and/or closed, you run a real risk of getting a (temporary) question ban soon. See [this topic about question bans](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days) for more information about this, and what you can do to prevent it.

Comment: Thank you Jeen, that feels bad. It is hard to do it on a different way with my knowledge or experience. A factor might be that i really work everyday from 10 o clock till 24 o clock. I am writing my master thesis and it is getting pretty close to the end. I feel like i am learning so much from you guys. I wish you could see my progress that i make on the back of feedback you give to me. Im sure others can learn from question and also from my mistakes!! All i can say i am really thankfull for all of this.

Comment: Domains and ranges of object properties are supposed to be classes. From my point of view it doesn't make sense to use specific countries as domain or range. Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domains and ranges of object properties are supposed to be classes. From my point of view it doesn't make sense to use specific countries as domain or range. Are you sure about this?

The typical way would be to use a class `Country` and use this as range of the object property `travelTo`. There is no specific construct for range in DL syntax, but a range axiom is just syntactic sugar.

Given that `r` is the object property and `C` the domain (resp. range), you can express it in DL syntax with:

Domain(r, C):

`∃r.⊤ ⊑ C`

Range(r, C):

`⊤ ⊑ ∀ r.C`

Comment: Thank you AKSW that was what i was looking for. Are you sure (Range(r,C) is correct. Shouldn't we introduce another variable for the range instead using C which is the domain? And what is T standing for?

Comment: Range is the relation type, and as I said there is no keyword in DL syntax. It's just abstract syntax. I've also seen people writing `ran(r,C)`. It was just an example with a class `C`. And `C` is a concrete class in your domain. In your example it would be `∃r.travelTo ⊑ Person` if we assume `Person` to be the domain of the property `travelTo`. `⊤` is the top concept, i.e. `owl:Thing`.

Comment: thank you now everything is clear to me!!  You already deserve a place in the chapter "acknowledgment" of my thesis,:P But for my own good, i should better not do it :P